# Getting typescript to work for Angular 2 project with facebook login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to get up and running with Angular 2 and typescript. So far so good, but I am having some troubles to get a Facebook login message working. I found a project [on github that demonstrated how this can be done](https://github.com/guilhermevrs/ng2-facebook). In this example, they have the following connector:

**fbconnector.ts**

```
export class FBConnector {

    constructor(appID: string) {
        if (!window.fbAsyncInit) {
            console.log('define');
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId: appID,
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.5'
                });
            };
        }
    }

    initFB() {
        var js: any,
            id = 'facebook-jssdk',
            ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

        if (document.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }

        js = document.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }

}
```

This gives the following 2 errors when I am compiling my typescript:

```
error TS2339: Property fbAsyncInit does not exist on type 'Window'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FB'.
```

This makes sense when you think about it, typescript needs these variables defined. I guess this is partly because I am new to typescript, but I don't exactly know how this should be done. Should I make a custom typings file? Or should I use workarounds? (For example adding  in front of window?)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually found the answer, DefinitelyTyped has type definitions for the Facebook Javascript SDK ([over here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts)).

All I had to do was add the file and reference to it with the following line at the top of my file:

`/// <reference path="../../../typings/main/ambient/fbsdk/index.d.ts" />`

Comment: Can you give some details, on top of which file did you add the code above?

Comment: attached link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can install typings by: `typings install -SG dt~fbsdk`

Comment: I installed typings like above, and indeed Sublime 3 does not highlight errors anymore. However ng server keeps throwing the same error "Property 'fbAsyncInit' does not exist on type 'Window'".